# What order are andWhere(), orWhere(), where() methods evaluated in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I'm confused as to something I've read on the CakePHP 3 documentation Query Builder's Advanced Conditions: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions

It gives the following code

```
$query = $articles->find()
->where(['author_id' => 2])
->orWhere(['author_id' => 3])
->andWhere([
    'published' => true,
    'view_count >' => 10
])
->orWhere(['promoted' => true]);
```

And says this is equivalent to this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE (promoted = true
OR (
  (published = true AND view_count > 10)
  AND (author_id = 2 OR author_id = 3)
))
```

I don't follow how that works at all, since the order of the conditions in the PHP are not the same as the order in the SQL statement that's generated (for example `->orWhere(['promoted' => true])` is last in PHP but first in the SQL statement. Why?).

The only information in the documentation that might be of relevance is where it says:

> Each method sets the combining operator used between the current and
>   previous condition.

Is this an error in the documentation, or can someone explain how this really works in a better way?

Whilst I realise this is almost certainly wrong, my understanding of how that SQL would evaluate is:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE (author_id = 2 OR author_id = 3)
AND ( (published = true AND view_count > 10) OR promoted = true)
```

Comment: @JasonJoslin I don't think you actually understand this question. You provided an answer based on alphabetical ordering (and subsequently deleted it because it's rubbish). It's to do with the order in which `OR` and `AND` conditions appear in the query - which very much affects the query results and will certainly *not* produce the same results unless the query generated was always the same given a certain set of PHP conditions.

Answer (score 1):

When you use orWhere query builder it takes the whole where clauses and make it pot at one side of the OR operator that's why it's like this

```
WHERE (
   promoted = true
   OR 
   (
      (published = true AND view_count > 10)
      AND 
      (author_id = 2 OR author_id = 3)
   )
)
```

You have to put it like this to get the desired output

```
    $query = $this->Orders->find()
        ->where(['author_id' => 2])
        ->orWhere(['author_id' => 3])
        ->andWhere([
            'OR'=>[
                ['promoted' => true],
                ['published' => true,
                    'view_count >' => 10]
            ]
        ]);
```

OR

```
     $query = $this->Orders->find()
            ->where(['author_id' => 2])
            ->orWhere(['author_id' => 3])
            ->andWhere(function (QueryExpression $exp) {
                return $exp->or_([
                    'promoted' => true,
                    ['published' => true,
                        'view_count >' => 10]
                ]);
            })->toArray();
```

Comment: Things can be a little confusing... both, `andWhere()` and `orWhere()` will take the whole existing stack of conditions and combine them with the news conditions. However additionally `orWhere()` does seem to behave differently than intended (documented), ie it will prepend the new conditions, while `andWhere()` appends them. That won't change the logic, but it surely can add to the confusion.